# "Increase" of a register in VHDL and hardware synthesis

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, signal, register, hdl

Suppose you have already defined a register (for instance called "reg") in VHDL, for instance as a vectors of 4 bit.

Now consider the operation: reg <= reg + 0001; it is like reg ++ in C.

My questions are:

1) how can reg store the result of the sum between reg itself and another number? The result is expressed by 4 sum bits and 1 carry bit, so there are 5 bits...

2) how will the synthesis be? An adder which takes 0001 and reg as input will give 5 output wires... How will they be connected to reg  (which has only 4 input wires)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carry-out is ignored in such expressions. If you care about it, you need to account for it explicitly. For example, you could write something like this:

```
-- perform the addition, making room for the carry-out
signal sum : std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
sum <= ("0" & reg) + "00001";

-- update the register and capture the carry-out at the same time
process ...
    reg <= sum (3 downto 0);
    carry <= sum (4);
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second line (of code) be in the process block to be executed?

Comment: @SimeonR No because the second line of code and the process have to be concurrential. Do not forget that in a process, instructions are sequential and that a signal is only updated at the END of a process.

If you want to place the second line in the process block, then you have to declare sum as a variable instead of as a signal.

Comment: Code in a hardware description language (VHDL or Verilog) is not "executed". Instead it is a description of the hardware that performs the desired computation. In this case, the `sum <= ...` line describes a combinatorial adder, so it does not appear inside a clocked process. In contrast to that, the `reg <= ...` line describes a register (flip-flops) that only gets updated on the specified clock edge, so it appears inside a clocked process.

Answer (score 0):

1) if your register is 4-bit wide, then the carry bit will be discarded.

What you will achieve is not reg + 1 but (reg + 1) % 16

For example if reg = 1111 (reg = 15) then reg + 1 = (1)0000 (= 16) but the carry bit will be discarded so reg will contain 0000 (= 0 = 16 % 16)

2) I'm not sure about the synthesis, and I guess it will depend on your FPGA and your synthesis tool. But I guess it will synthesis an adder with no carry output or synthesis the correct adder but left the carry output unconnected.

Comment: There will be no register or gate for that carry after synthesis.